# YoastSEO: sitemap last modified date does not update

Tags: wordpress, sitemap

I've been updating some content on our product categories like descriptions, headers, titles and yoast seo settings, but I noticed that in our xml sitemap the last modified date doesn't update. Do I have to do something else for it to update? I've checked for cache plugin's and we don't have one so it's definitely not about the cache.

Answer (score 3):

I just found out that you need to update one of the products under that category for the last modified date to be updated.

Comment: Google would discover the updated content without the sitemap anyhow.

Comment: Yes, but if your site is not well linked, this helps google to make sense of your site.

Comment: So your site uses WordPress and Yoast? and you have pages that can't be navigated to? thought not :)

Comment: Yes and no. Our product category pages can just be reached using filters and not by a link like the nav menu. I just took over the site that was built for us by a local web developer company and I'm trying to fix it.